# How to perform this query

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table in my data base (Job Cards), which has a column called 'JobCardNum'. This is the primary key for the table, however there are gaps because a particular job card may have been deleted.

For example the may exist Job Cards with number 2000 and 2002 but there is no 2001.

What I need to is take a JobCard Number as an input and find what the next Job Card Number would be if the column was in ascending order.

So if '$num' is my sanitised input, I need something like

```
 "SELECT * FROM JobCards WHERE JobCardNum = $num ORDER BY 'JobCardNum' [asc]"
```

But then get the 'next' JobCardNum.

I know I could return an array of all JobCards then extract the one I need but there could be thousands of entries so this seems inefficient.

Any Ideas

Comment: mysql or Microsoft sql-server ?

Comment: @Drew The Microsoft SQL Server tag is `sql-server`, not `sql`.

Comment: mySQL is what i need

Comment: @TomH I am not clueless to this fact. The answer below was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 JobCardNum FROM JobCards WHERE JobCardNum > $num ORDER BY JobCardNum asc
```

mysql:

```
SELECT JobCardNum from someTable WHERE JobCardNum > $num ORDER BY JobCardNum  limit 1
```

Comment: Where do I specify the table ?

Comment: In addition to missing the `FROM` clause, MySQL uses the `LIMIT` syntax, not `TOP`.

Comment: @Drew Why did you edit in your own answer to this, rather than posting your own?

Comment: @Siyual Because Robert was using Microsoft Sql Server syntax. I like to help the little guy. As if I need more answers on this site daily.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the `JobCardNum` then this is valid in all SQL dialects:

```
SELECT MIN(JobCardNum) AS JobCardNum
FROM JobCards
WHERE JobCardNum >= $num
```

For MySQL you can use this to get all of the columns:

```
SELECT
    JobCardNum,
    SomeOtherColumn,
    ... <list the columns, never use SELECT *>
FROM
    JobCards
WHERE
    JobCardNum >= $num
LIMIT 1
```

If you wanted to use ANSI SQL, rather than rely on MySQL's `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT
    JobCardNum,
    SomeOtherColumn,
    ... <list the columns, never use SELECT *>
FROM
    JobCards JC
WHERE
    JobCardNum = (SELECT MIN(JobCardNum) AS JobCardNum FROM JobCards WHERE JobCardNum >= $num)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `JobCardNum = $num` you could say that `JobCardNum` should be greater than or equal `$num`:

```
"SELECT * FROM JobCards WHERE JobCardNum >= $num ORDER BY 'JobCardNum' asc"
```

This will return a list of all data with a minimum of `$num` for`JobCardNum`.
As you just want one result, you could limit it to 1:

```
"SELECT * FROM JobCards WHERE JobCardNum >= $num ORDER BY 'JobCardNum' asc LIMIT 1"
```